# Google Fi on Windows phone

Tags: settings, cellular-data, google, blu-win-hd

I subscribed to [Google Fi](https://fi.google.com) using esim on Google Pixed 3a XL phone and transferred phone number.

But I have Windows phone BLU WIN HD LTE with the sim and what to use it for Google Fi too.

For this I need to change [APN settings](https://apn.gishan.net/en/apn/project-fi/blu-win-hd-lte) and I changed to h2g2, but phone still can't connect to network.

How to fix it?

**Explaining**: As I understand from [this article](https://medium.com/@panteliszirinis/project-fi-activating-internationally-and-using-it-as-a-digital-nomad-on-nexus-and-iphone-687b04f4cf32), I can use the same Google Fi number on two phones: one with esim, and other sim. But it work with esim, but doesn't work on Windows phone with real sim.

Comment: Are you able to test the SIM card in another phone?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder, I can only 2 phones, and sim doesn't work in this Windows phone, but maybe Google Fi number can work only on one phone at the same time?

Comment: Do you have data access on the phone with the SIM card? Technically it can work with 100000 phones if Google choose to.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder, no data, only wifi works. But maybe I can use only data sim on the second phone?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder, Google customer service? No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's customer service should be able to convert your old Fi SIM Card into a data-only card (just give them the numbers on the card. If they can't then you'll have to order the data-only SIM Cards.

If you want to have voice on multiple phones you'll sadly need to install the Hangouts app on those phones and it has never been made available for Windows Phone.

Comment: so, second sim can be only for data?

Comment: @Alexan seems so. Why won't you contact customer service?

Comment: just found this: https://support.google.com/fi/forum/AAAARQbf-us7uzwZoBoR1E/?hl=en&gpf=d/topic/project-fi/7uzwZoBoR1E

Comment: @Alexan they say you need the hangouts app (which can be used with any sim at all). That app has never been made available on Windows Phone by Google.

Comment: I just thought it can be second voice phone, but it looks like it is not.